# Laravel 5.4 - controller logic to show the status of a blog post on view

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

new to Laravel, and just having this problem that I couldn't figure it out.

I have a post controller set up to query out all blog posts.  On the database, I have a integer column and named as "status", 0 as inactive, 1 as active.  The question is how and where to place the logic to check whetherthe status is 0 or 1, and show  "inactive" or "active" in the view.  Thanks in advance.

```
public function index()
{

    $posts = Post::where('user_id', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('post.index')->withPosts($posts);
}
```

Here is the view

```
<table class="table"> 
        <tr>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{datePretty($post->created_at) }}</td>
            <td><a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>


        <br>

    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have that logic inside your blade template:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>{{datePretty($post->created_at) }}</td>
        <td><a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></td>
        <td>@if($post->status) active @else inactive @endif</td>
    </tr>


    <br>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Is it possible to toss the logic in the controller so it can keep the view as clean as possible?

Comment: it's fine to have `display logic` inside a view. If you really want to keep it the controller, you have 2 options: iterate over the posts array and add active/inactive or modify your sql query to return inactive/active base on the status value (using `case` statement)